# eliminación al final de una pila en C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

tengo este código de pila en lenguaje c, lo que quiero hacer con este código es poder modificarlo y ponerle la opción de que elimine el numero que se encuentre al final de la lista, que vendría siendo el primer numero introducido, sin embargo no lo he conseguido y solo logro que se elimine desde el inicio osea los números que han sido introducidos recientemente.

¿Cómo podría lograr en el código que se elimine el numero localizado al final?

básicamente lo que quiero que suceda al escoger la opción de eliminar al final si tengo en la lista por ejemplo

4->3->2->1

que se elimine el 1
y quede

4->3->2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lista {
    int clave;
    struct lista * sig;
};

struct lista * inicio = NULL;
struct lista * nuevo;
struct lista * aux;
struct lista * anterior;
struct lista * ultimo;
int contador;
int n;

void insertar();
void desapilar();

int main() {
    int opcionMenu = 0;
    do {

        printf("\n\n|           pila        ");

        printf("\n| 1. Apilar");
        printf("\n| 2. Desapilar");
        printf("\n| 3. Salir");
        printf("\n\n Escoja una Opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", & opcionMenu);
        switch (opcionMenu) {
        case 1:
            printf("\n\n INSERTAR  \n\n");
            insertar();
            break;
        case 2:
            desapilar();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n\n Programa finalizado...");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\n Opcion No Valida \n\n");
        }
    } while (opcionMenu != 3);
    return 0;
}

void insertar()
{
    
    while(contador<4)
    {

        nuevo = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        nuevo->clave=(n+1);
        n++;

        if (inicio == NULL) {

            nuevo-> sig = inicio;
            inicio = nuevo;
            ultimo=nuevo;
            contador++;
        } else 

        {
            ultimo->sig=nuevo->sig;
            nuevo-> sig = inicio;
            inicio = nuevo;
            contador++;
        }
    }

    {
        aux = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        aux = inicio;
        if (inicio != NULL) {
            while (aux != NULL) {
                printf("%d->", aux -> clave);
                aux = aux -> sig;
            }
        } else {
            printf("\n La pila se encuentra Vacia\n\n");
        }
    }
}

void desapilar() {
    nuevo = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    printf(" Dato Desapilado: ");

    if (inicio != NULL) {
        aux = inicio;
        inicio = inicio -> sig;

        free(aux);
        contador--;
    }

    {

        aux = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        aux = inicio;
        if (inicio != NULL) {
            while (aux != NULL) {
                printf("%d->", aux -> clave);
                aux = aux -> sig;
            }
        } else {
            printf("\n La pila se encuentra Vacia\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que librerar `ultimo` y poner el **antepenúltimo bloque** apuntando a `NULL` como siguiente bloque. Es decir

```
 ---------     ---------
|clave: 1| -> |clave: 2| -> NULL 
 ---------     ---------
```

Debe pasar a

```
 ---------    
|clave: 1|  -> NULL 
 ---------
```

El problema de esto es que no sabes cuál es el penúltimo para eso debes iterar

```
void desapilar() {
    nuevo = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    printf(" Dato Desapilado: ");

    if (inicio != NULL) {
        if (inicio == ultimo) {
            free(inicio);
            inicio = NULL;
            ultimo = NULL;
        } else {
            aux = inicio;
            while (aux -> sig != ultimo) {
                aux = aux -> sig;
            }
            aux -> sig = NULL;
            free(ultimo);
            ultimo = aux;
        }
        contador--;
    }

    {

        aux = (struct lista * ) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        aux = inicio;
        if (inicio != NULL) {
            while (aux != NULL) {
                printf("%d->", aux -> clave);
                aux = aux -> sig;
            }
        } else {
            printf("\n La pila se encuentra Vacia\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que se hace en esta función es básicamente

```
if (inicio == ultimo) {
     free(inicio);
     inicio = NULL;
     ultimo = NULL;
}
```

Si `incio` y `ultimo` son los mismos, entonces quiere decir que solo hay un bloque, por lo que liberamos el espacio de `inicio` (o `ultimo` en este caso daría lo mismo dado que apuntan a la misma memoria) u a los dos los igualamos a `NULL`

```
else {
    aux = inicio;
    while (aux -> sig != ultimo) {
        aux = aux -> sig;
    }
    aux -> sig = NULL;
    free(ultimo);
    ultimo = aux;
}
```

En esta parte del `else` igualamos `aux` a `inicio` e iteramos hasta el siguiente, cuando veamos que `aun -> sig` es igual al `ultimo` quiere decir que estamos en el **penúltimo**, que es el bloque que nos interesa, por lo que dejamos de iterar. Después igualamos `aux -> sig` a NULL, dado que ahora este bloque será nuestro último bloque. Por lo tanto liberamos la memoria de `ultimo` y luego igualamos `ultimo` al **penúltimo bloque**